# Rails 4 - Bundle error for obfuscate_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to `$bundle install` the `obfuscate_id` gem into my Rails 4 application, but I am coming across an error:

[image: Bundle error for obfuscate_id]

It says it's dependent on Rails > 3.2.1, but I have Rails 4.0.2. Am I wrong in assuming this should work? Have I missed something?

The gem: https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: It says it's dependent on Rails ~ 3.2.1.

Comment: Yes, but it says in the gemspec ">= 3.2.15". Is that not greater than or equals to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. RubyGems doesn't seem to have the most recent version, so I installed the gem from Github, which resolved it. Put the following code in your file:

```
gem 'obfuscate_id', :git => 'https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id.git'
```

Comment: Now getting error: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    obfuscate_id (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (~> 4.2.0) ruby

    rails (4.0.8)